# Whole words in python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

How do I find whole words using regular expressions in Python? 
I use Beautiful soup and re library to parse a document. In soup I need to find all contents after word 'E-mail'. I try

```
for sublink in link.findAll(text = re.compile("[E-mail:0-9a-zA-Z]")):
         print sublink.encode('utf-8')
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Give an example of input you have and the output you expect.

Comment: And what comes after 'E-mail' is considered as a word (`\w+`) ?

Comment: I expect everything after the 'E-mail:' including it, instead I have all the text in the soup.
Sample input is
`code`
<tr>
        <td>
         <br/>
        </td>
        <td height="23" valign="bottom">
         Email:
         <script type="text/javascript">
          var a='@';
            a+='rmb-velas.';a+='ru';
            var b='info';
            document.write("<a href='");
            document.write(['mail','to:',b,a].join(''));
            document.write("'>");
            document.write([b,a].join(''));
            document.write("</a>");
         </script>
        </td>
`code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example for word extraction via regular expressions:

```py
import re

text = "First line\n" + \
    "Second line\n" + \
    "Important line! E-mail:mail@domain.de, Phone:991\n" + \
    "Another important line! E-mail:tom@gmail.com, Phone:001\n" + \
    "Another line"
print text

emails = re.findall("E-mail:([\w@.-]+)", text)
print "Found email(s): " + ', '.join(emails)
```

Output:

```
Found email(s): mail@domain.de, tom@gmail.com
```

Not sure if that's what you are looking for.

**Edit:** The characters `0-9a-zA-Z` can be written as `\w`. And yes, I added `.` and `-`. Simply put them into `[\w@.-]` if there are more possible characters.

Comment: `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` can be written as `\w`

Comment: If you you surround `[\w@.-]+` in parentheses, then you only get the emails.  i.e., the output is "mail@domain.de, tom@gmail.com" instead of "Email:mail@domain.de, Email:tom@gmail.com".

Comment: Sure. The OP's code example looked like she wants to include 'E-mail:'. But you're right. She actually tries to "find all contents after word 'E-mail'".

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. 
It doesn't work with my document - the output is just empty. Perhaps the matter is the soup object..